# wysihtml5: font size is not overriding earlier font sizes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, font-size, wysihtml5

I have written a small web-app where you can edit documents via the wysihtml5 Editor, like on this site: http://wysihtml.com.

after a few problems, quite everything worked fine, but now i recognized that when i change the font-size to 20 and put it back to 14 it still stays on font size 20 and both html-tags are used. Like this:

```
<span class="wysiwyg-font-size-20 wysiwyg-font-size-16">used font-size 20 at first, after i used 16, still stays on 20.</span>
```

and it looks just a bit bigger than this:

> used font-size 20 at first, after i used 16, still stays on 20.

Anyone a clue what it could be?

greetings

Comment: is this problem occur in production?

Comment: yes, occurs in both production and develoment

Comment: anyone?............

Comment: are you using rich text editor?

Comment: yes, as written in the Question. wysihtml5 and rich text editor are the same, right?

Comment: can you check generated code when you add text content

Comment: it generates the code you see in my question, but i think it's adding the fonts instead of overriding

Comment: anyone? still having this problem